# Looping Background Music in Java?

Tags: java, embedded-resource, playback, javasound

I am trying to get music to play in my application and I have this code but I just get a null pointer exception. The file is in the correct directory so I don't know where I'm slipping up.

```
public void startBGMusic(){
    AudioPlayer myBackgroundPlayer = AudioPlayer.player;
    ContinuousAudioDataStream myLoop = null;
    try {
          AudioStream myBackgroundMusic = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getResource("Act/Music/OverTheInferno.wav").toURI())));
          AudioData myData = myBackgroundMusic.getData();
          myLoop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(myData);
    }catch(Exception error){
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
        System.out.println(error);
    }
    myBackgroundPlayer.start(myLoop);  
}
```

Comment: I'd start by tossing out the assumption that `"the file is in the correct directory"` and work from there. You need to **prove** that it's in the right directory first. I would avoid the mega-chaining that you're doing on that one line, separate the method calls, and test each for nulls. Also, why are you trying to convert a resource into a File? Why not just use an InputStream?

Comment: Instead, I'd use `getResourceAsStream(...)` and pass it into the AudioStream, after first checking that it's not null.

Comment: 1) By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`  3) For looping sounds, you really can't go past the Java Sound based `Clip`.  See a working example on the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Answer (score 1):

I would change this:

```
AudioStream myBackgroundMusic = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(
   new File(getClass().getResource("Act/Music/OverTheInferno.wav").toURI())));
```

to something like this:

```
AudioStream myBackgroundMusic = new AudioStream(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("Act/Music/OverTheInferno.wav"));
```

Also:

- I would check to make sure that the stream is not null before using it.
- I would not catch any and all Exceptions, just the specific ones that I'm looking for.
- And would print out the Exception's stacktrace.